# i am getting an error while calling a method and storing its object

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I'm trying to create an activity where i can select a particular row from the ListView which is being retrived from the database so that i can manipulate it but when I'm selecting that row my application unfortunately stops.

[Here I am getting a android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmUgV.png)
While trying to select a row from the database i'm getting an runtime exception.

this is my databasehelper class

```
databasehelper.java

package com.example.ashwanislaptop.expensemanager;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="Transaction.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="transaction_table";
    public static final String COL_1="ID";
    public static final String COL_2="PRICE";
    public static final String COL_3="DATE";
    public static final String COL_4="TIME";
    public static final String COL_5="DESCRIPTION";
    public static final String COL_6="CATEGORY";
    public static final String COL_7="PAYMENT_MODE";
    private static final String TAG="DatabaseHelper";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,PRICE INTEGER NOT NULL,DATE TEXT NOT NULL,TIME TEXT NOT NULL,DESCRIPTION TEXT NOT NULL,CATEGORY TEXT NOT NULL,PAYMENT_MODE TEXT NOT NULL);");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS transaction_table");
        onCreate(db);
    }



    void InsertData(Transaction t){
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_2,t.getPrice());
        cv.put(COL_3,t.getDate());
        cv.put(COL_4,t.getTime());
        cv.put(COL_5,t.getDescription());
        cv.put(COL_6,t.getCategory());
        cv.put(COL_7,t.getPayment_mode());
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
        db.close();
    }
    public ArrayList<Transaction> getAllTransaction() {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Log.i(TAG, "getAllTransaction: getting Transaction Record");
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * From transaction_table", null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            ArrayList<Transaction> list = new ArrayList<>();
            do {
                Transaction t = new Transaction(c.getString(1),c.getString(2), c.getString(5));
                list.add(t);
                Log.i(TAG, "GetAllTranscRecords: one record retrieved");

            }while (c.moveToNext());
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"No record found");
            db.close();
            return null;
        }
    }
[getting an runtime error while calling it from the Transaction_Detail.java]


    ***Transaction getAllTransactionssecond(int idd) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getAllTransactionssecond: "+idd);
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
     Log.i(TAG, "getAllTransaction: getting Transaction Record of id "+idd);
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("Select * From transaction_table where id="+idd+";", null);
```

[The Execution crashes exactly at this point how do i send the data to the Transaction_details so that i can print the data in the textviews]
                    Transaction t = new Transaction(c.getString(1),c.getString(2),c.getString(3),c.getString(4),c.getString(5),c.getString(6));
                    Log.i(TAG, "GetAllTranscRecords: one record retrieved");
           // Log.i(TAG,"No record found");
            db.close();
            return t;
        }***

```
    public ArrayList<Transaction> getAllTransactioncategorywise(){

        SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
        Log.i(TAG,"getAllTransaction: getting Transaction Record");
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("Select * From transaction_table order by "+COL_6+";",null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            ArrayList<Transaction> list=new ArrayList<>();
            do{
                Transaction t=new Transaction(c.getString(1),c.getString(2),c.getString(5));
                list.add(t);
                Log.i(TAG,"GetAllTranscRecords: one record retrieved");

            }while (c.moveToNext());
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"No record found");
            db.close();
            return null;
        }
    }
    public ArrayList<Transaction> getAllTransactiondatewise(){

        SQLiteDatabase db=getReadableDatabase();
        Log.i(TAG,"getAllTransaction: getting Transaction Record");
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("Select * From transaction_table order by "+COL_3+" desc",null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            ArrayList<Transaction> list=new ArrayList<>();
            do{
                Transaction t=new Transaction(c.getString(1),c.getString(2),c.getString(5));
                list.add(t);
                Log.i(TAG,"GetAllTranscRecords: one record retrieved");

            }while (c.moveToNext());
            return list;
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i(TAG,"No record found");
            db.close();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

[This is my Transaction Details Class]

```
transaction detail.java
package com.example.ashwanislaptop.expensemanager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Transaction_Details extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView txtid,txtprice,txtdate,txttime,txtcateg,txtpayment,txtdecription;
    private DatabaseHelper ta;
    public static final String TAG="Trasaction detail";
    public  int  sentid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transaction__details);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: before intent");
        Intent i1=getIntent();
        sentid=i1.getIntExtra("STRING",0);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: after intent "+sentid);

        txtid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtid);
        txtdate=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdate);
        txttime=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txttime);
        txtcateg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtcateg);
        txtpayment=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtpayment);
        txtdecription=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtdescription);
        ta=new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

[ I'm able to retrieve the data]

```
        **Transaction details=ta.getAllTransactionssecond(sentid);**



        txtid.setText(details.getId());
        txtdate.setText(details.getDate());
        txttime.setText(details.getTime());
        txtcateg.setText(details.getCategory());
        txtprice.setText(details.getPrice());
        txtpayment.setText(details.getPayment_mode());
        txtdecription.setText(details.getDescription());
    }
}

Transaction.java
package com.example.ashwanislaptop.expensemanager;


public class Transaction  {
    private int id;
    private String price,date,time,description,category,payment_mode;

    public Transaction() {
    }

    public Transaction(int id, String price, String date, String time, String description, String category, String payment_mode) {
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.description = description;
        this.category = category;
        this.payment_mode = payment_mode;
    }

    public Transaction(String price, String date, String time, String description, String category, String payment_mode) {
        this.price = price;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.description = description;
        this.category = category;
        this.payment_mode = payment_mode;
    }

    public Transaction(String price, String date, String category) {
        this.category = category;
        this.date = date;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getPayment_mode() {
        return payment_mode;
    }

    public void setPayment_mode(String payment_mode) {
        this.payment_mode = payment_mode;
    }
}
```

[This is my AllTransaction Class]

```
AllTansactionFragment.java
package com.example.ashwanislaptop.expensemanager;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Welcome on 06-Aug-16.
 */
public class AllTransactionFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG="AllTransactionFragment";
    private ListView listView;
    private DatabaseHelper ta=null;
    //private ArrayAdapter<String> aa=null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vu=inflater.inflate(R.layout.alltransactionlistview,container,false);
        listView=(ListView)vu.findViewById(R.id.lvtransaction);
        ta=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateView:"+ta);
        ArrayList<Transaction> list=ta.getAllTransactiondatewise();

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Transaction>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Transaction t1, Transaction t2) {
                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
                if(t1.getDate()==null || t2.getDate()==null)
                    return 0;
                return t1.getDate().compareTo(t2.getDate());
            }
        });

        TransactionListAdapter aa=new TransactionListAdapter(getActivity(),list);
        listView.setAdapter(aa);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Log.i(TAG, " onItemClick: ");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Clicked on:"+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent ii=new Intent(getActivity(),Transaction_Details.class);
                ii.putExtra("STRING",i);
                Log.i(TAG, "onItemClick: after");
                startActivity(ii);
            }
        });

       return vu;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your `DatabaseHelper`. It is null.

Comment: working thank u very much but android-database-cursorindexoutofboundsexception this runtime error is coming and the app is crashing at the time of clicking the listview please help me out